# Factory Array can be pushed but not replaced

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this factory

**DatosFactory.js**

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('InmoManager')

    .factory('DatosFactory', function($http, $location) {
        var datos = {
            propiedadesFiltradas: []
        }

        ...

        datos.getPropiedadesFiltradas = function(){
            return datos.propiedadesFiltradas;
        }

        datos.setPropiedadesFiltradas = function(data){
            datos.propiedadesFiltradas.length = 0;
            datos.propiedadesFiltradas.push(data);
        }

        return datos;
    })
})();
```

This controller

**SidebarController.js**

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('InmoManager')

    .controller('SidebarController', function($http, $scope, DatosFactory) {

        var sidebarCtrl = this;

        sidebarCtrl.toggleSidebar = function(){
            $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
        }

        sidebarCtrl.propiedades = DatosFactory.getPropiedadesFiltradas();

    });
})();
```

Making this work

**pageSidebar.html**

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="propiedad in sidebarCtrl.propiedades[0] | orderBy:'titulo'">
```

This works great!, but, i want to change this:

```
ng-repeat="propiedad in sidebarCtrl.propiedades[0]"
```

to

```
ng-repeat="propiedad in sidebarCtrl.propiedades"
```

and this

```
datos.setPropiedadesFiltradas = function(data){
    datos.propiedadesFiltradas.length = 0;
    datos.propiedadesFiltradas.push(data);
}
```

to

```
datos.setPropiedadesFiltradas = function(data){
    datos.propiedadesFiltradas = data;
}
```

But when i make this, the variable `sidebarCtrl.propiedades` get's undefined (doesn't update when i call `datos.setPropiedadesFiltradas()`

Comment: Did you tried datos.propiedadesFiltradas = [] and then datos.propiedadesFiltradas.push(data);

Comment: Yes, and didn't work because of dfsq answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you reassign `datos.propiedadesFiltradas = data;` you break the object reference, and as the result `datos.propiedadesFiltradas` is no longer points to the object Angular set up bindings to.

On the other hand, when you push object reference stays untouched, and Angular's changes tracking engine can detect changes and rerender view.

One more thing. I would recommend you to use [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive instead of `$('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');`:

```
sidebarCtrl.toggleSidebar = function() {
    sidebarCtrl.toggle = !sidebarCtrl.toggle;
}
```

and in HTML

```
<div id="wrapper" ng-class={toggled: toggle}>...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of dfsq answer i assume that all i wanted it's not possible, but i found this "partial" solution

With this in the factory:

```
    datos.setPropiedadesFiltradas = function(data){
        datos.propiedadesFiltradas.length = 0;
        datos.propiedadesFiltradas.push.apply(datos.propiedadesFiltradas,data);
    }
```

i could change this:

```
    ng-repeat="propiedad in sidebarCtrl.propiedades[0]"
```

to

```
    ng-repeat="propiedad in sidebarCtrl.propiedades"
```